# On hovering mouse on image to zoom magento displaying zoomed image twice either on zoom and in background zoom block

Tags: image, magento, cloud, zooming

I have uploaded 3 images of a product in magento, so when i am viewing my product on my [site](http://bluegape.com/shop-by-events/fathersday/mugs/i-love-you-dad-high-quality-ceramic-mug),
on zooming it show number of images are 4 and on hover the zoomed images displays as it is in background of the zoom block.

Answer (score 0):

first of all thanks for posting your site URL.

As i trace your html code on live site.

To solve your issue that would be 2 ways to solve it.

**1)** As i seen your third image has white background so it is not visible in background of same image when we are applying zoom effect on it, but another 2 images of mug are display in back ground, the main thing i notice that for 2 mug images are transperant images and 3rd one is not transparent. so here i am suggesting to you to make background of image white or

**2)** You can apply effect of color when user will show image in zoom.

Let me know if i can help you more.

Comment: Hey Liyakat, thanks for your answer, i noticed it with my images & finally i found the problem, it was with images,

Comment: Welcome @PratyushGoyal, i will be glad, i am requesting you to accept my answer, so in in future if some one has some issue, they will take help from here.